# c++ Array setters and getters

Tags: c++, arrays, setter, getter

I need help with making setters and getters in c++ for these variables.

```
char name[20];
    double homeworkGrades[6];
    double quizGrades[6];
    double examGrades[4];
```

Comment: If you can use `std::string`, `std::array`/`std::vector` instead of raw arrays.  They are much easier to work with.

Comment: You need to add some more context and post a [mcve].

Comment: You can't really have getters and setters for variables. Perhaps you mean member variables? Even then how you write the getter and setter depends a lot on how these entities are being used (which you don't tell us). More context is needed.

Comment: you dont need "setters" and "getters" for those variables. You "get" a reference to an element via `name[index]`. Anything beyond that requires more context, but is not obvious from what you posted currently. Please add more information to the question

Answer (score 0):

Requesting setters and getters imply that you have a class with data members you want to encapsulate. Here's an example:

```cpp
class Student
{
public:
    explicit Student( std::string name )
        : _name{ std::move( name ) }
    {}

    std::string GetName() const { return _name; } // Getter only; set at construction time

    double GetHomework( int index ) const
    {
        return _homework.at( index ); // Throws if out of range
    }

    void SetHomework( int index, double grade )
    {
        _homework.at( index ) = grade;
    }

    // ...

private:
    const std::string     _name;
    std::array<double, 6> _homework;
    // ... etc.
};
```

The Student class has getters and setters for its properties. The advantage is that you can do error checking (here done with the `std::array::at()` function for range checking), thread protection, file/network I/O, caching, etc.